# Can't solve "loop" problem on Queue list in C

Tags: c, list, pointers, struct, queue

I'm working with pointers, lists and structs. I have a program that reads data from a text file and saves it in a struct. After converting all the data into nodes, I tried printing the list. The output in console was as if the program was stuck in a loop, printing only the last node forever.

This was my initial code. I use `initFromText()` to open the text file and save every line as a node.
Inside this function I call `enqueue()`, which is supposed to add the new node to the end of the list, pointing to `NULL`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 35

typedef struct temperature{
    float temperature;
    struct temperature *next;
} Temperature;

typedef struct patient{
    char name[25];
    int age;
    int room;
    Temperature *firstTemp;
    struct patient *next;
} Patient;

void initFromText(Patient **first);
void enqueue(Patient **first, Patient *newP);
void printPatients(Patient *first);

int main(){
    Patient *first = NULL;
    initFromText(&first);
    printPatients(first);
    return 0;
}

void initFromText(Patient **first){
    FILE *file = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    if (file == NULL) return;

    char line[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
    Patient *newP = (Patient*)malloc(sizeof(Patient));
    Temperature *newT = (Temperature*)malloc(sizeof(Temperature));

    while(fgets(line, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, file)){
        char *name = strtok(line, ",");
        strcpy(newP->name, name);
        newP->age = atoi(strtok(NULL, ","));
        newP->room = atoi(strtok(NULL, ","));
        newT->temperature = atof(strtok(NULL, ","));
        newT->next = NULL;
        newP->firstTemp = newT;
        newP->next = NULL;
        enqueue(first, newP);
    }
    fclose(file);
}

void enqueue(Patient **first, Patient *newP){
    if (*first == NULL) *first = newP;
    else{
        Patient *current = *first;
        while (current->next != NULL) current = current->next;
        current->next = newP;
    }
}

void printPatients(Patient *first){
    if (first == NULL) printf("\n\n *No hay pacientes ingresados.\n");
    else{
        Patient *current = first;
        do{
            printf("\n********************");
            printf("\n  %s", current->name);
            printf("\nEdad: %d", current->age);
            printf("\nHabitacion: %d", current->room);
            printf("\nTemperaturas:");
            Temperature *currentTemp = current->firstTemp;
            do{
                printf("\n\t%.1f", currentTemp->temperature);
                currentTemp = currentTemp->next;
            }while(currentTemp != NULL);
            current = current->next;
            printf("\n********************");
        }while(current != NULL);
    }
}
```

In the execution, the program gets stuck in the loop I mentioned.
I have found that the problem is in the `enqueue()` function. I did the following:

Commented the `printPatients()` function in `main()`.

```
int main(){
    Patient *first = NULL;
    initFromText(&first);
    //printPatients(first);
    return 0;
}
```

Commented the `enqueue()` function, and printed the info of `newP` in every iteration. Every node was created correctly, pointing to `NULL`.

```
void initFromText(Patient **first){
    FILE *file = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    if (file == NULL) return;

    char line[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
    Patient *newP = (Patient*)malloc(sizeof(Patient));
    Temperature *newT = (Temperature*)malloc(sizeof(Temperature));

    while(fgets(line, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, file)){
        char *name = strtok(line, ",");
        strcpy(newP->name, name);
        newP->age = atoi(strtok(NULL, ","));
        newP->room = atoi(strtok(NULL, ","));
        newT->temperature = atof(strtok(NULL, ","));
        newT->next = NULL;
        newP->firstTemp = newT;
        newP->next = NULL;
        printf("\n********************");
        printf("\n  %s", newP->name);
        printf("\nEdad: %d", newP->age);
        printf("\nHabitacion: %d", newP->room);
        printf("\nTemperatura: %.1f", newP->firstTemp->temperature);
        printf("\nSiguiente: %s", newP->next->name);
        printf("\n********************");
        //enqueue(first, newP);
    }
    fclose(file);
}
```

Then, I repeated the process in the `enqueue()` function. The result was that the first node was created correctly, pointing to `NULL`, but then, every node was pointing to itself (`2nd->next = 2nd`, `3rd->next = 3rd`, etc). And apparently the "first" pointer ended up pointing to the last node. This way, the loop at the end of the program is printing the last node forever.

```
void enqueue(Patient **first, Patient *newP){
    if (*first == NULL) *first = newP;
    else{
        Patient *current = *first;
        while (current->next != NULL) current = current->next;
        current->next = newP;
    }
    printf("\n********************");
    printf("\n  %s", newP->name);
    printf("\nEdad: %d", newP->age);
    printf("\nHabitacion: %d", newP->room);
    printf("\nTemperatura: %.1f", newP->firstTemp->temperature);
    printf("\nSiguiente: %s", newP->next->name);
    printf("\n********************");
}
```

I have tried a lot of things, but can't understand what's the problem.

Comment: initFromText only creates one node.

Comment: @stark thanks, this made me understand how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I just had to move the following 2 lines of code:

```
Patient *newP = (Patient*)malloc(sizeof(Patient));
Temperature *newT = (Temperature*)malloc(sizeof(Temperature));
```

from here (initFromText())

```
char line[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
Patient *newP = (Patient*)malloc(sizeof(Patient));
Temperature *newT = (Temperature*)malloc(sizeof(Temperature));

while(fgets(line, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, file)){
```

to here

```
char line[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];

while(fgets(line, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, file)){
    Patient *newP = (Patient*)malloc(sizeof(Patient));
    Temperature *newT = (Temperature*)malloc(sizeof(Temperature));
```

This fixed the fact that I was creating just 1 node and recursively saving the data in it. Now it creates one node for every line of the txt file.